# Drupal front page and facebook crawlers

Tags: 6, social-network

I've got a drupal front_page that reditects all anonymous users from blogs to front page. But I want to facebook clawler see my og: data, to post comments with current title. Facebook crawler got 302 on front and takes title from front page.

How can I do a (maybe) whitelist to facebook crawler to take og: data from restricted area?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure how you are doing the redirect, but Facebook sends a USER AGENT string to signal its bot/crawler, so you could do something like:

```
  if (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'facebookexternalhit')!==FALSE) {
    // DON'T REDIRECT, we're facebook crawling around...
  } else {
    // REDIRECT, we are another bot or a user, etc...
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

It depends on way how you made the redirection. Rules? Then add condition that tests user-agent and identify if it is not FB crawler. If you don't like PHP snippets you can do it by check Context which tests user-agent.